# Mac OS X programming forum?

Tags: language-agnostic, macos, forum

Are there actively working Mac OS X programming forums?

Of course, SO is one of the best, but it would be better if I know some dedicated forums for Mac OS X programming issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like [MacRumors'](http://forums.macrumors.com/). There is a special subforum for Mac and iPhone programming. And of course, Apple's [official forum](http://discussions.apple.com/category.jspa?categoryID=164).

Answer (score 3):

It's also worth checking for similar proposals on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).  I know there's a proposal up for "power users of Apple hardware and software" but there may also be one for OS X development.  If not, go ahead and create one and see what kind of interest you can drum up.  If your proposal includes iOS development as well then you may get a lot of people from here, there are tons of iOS development questions posted here daily.